# git-svn-rebase is commiting to an SVN tag

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm just starting with git and using it to interact with an SVN repository.  The svn repo is in a standard format so I configured my sandbox as

```
git svn clone <repo> -s
```

All seemed fine initially but after several rebases, dcommits and tags I appear to be always commiting to an SVN tag.  Doing a dcommit dry run returns:

```
$ git svn dcommit --dry-run
Committing to http://proj.badc.rl.ac.uk/svn/badc/users/spascoe/metaconfig/tags/0.1.1 ...
diff-tree a1265119164b79cfb12d28a7059d453fb4eb13f7~1 a1265119164b79cfb12d28a7059d453fb4eb13f7
```

My .git/config is:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    autocrlf = false
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://proj.badc.rl.ac.uk/svn/badc
    fetch = users/spascoe/metaconfig/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = users/spascoe/metaconfig/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = users/spascoe/metaconfig/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Poking around in .git isn't helping.  Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "after several [...] tags?"

Comment: Even when I re-clone the SVN repository I end up committing to tags/0.1.1.

In the end I have solved this problem by making a dummy commit in SVN, recloning with git then merging my pending changes from 1 git repo to another.  I'm not back committing to svn trunk.

I'd still like to know how this mess might have happened :-)

Comment: @lindelof. To be honest I can't remember.  I think I tried "git tag" and found it didn't do anything to svn.  Then I did "svn tag" before finding I could use "git svn tag".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git svn` command had a bug where the master branch could be left pointing to something other than svn trunk when initially importing an svn repository.  It was fixed in git v1.6.5 and later (in [v1.6.5-rc0~75](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=b186a261b1f7ec1fbda8c5f6d84595f3a7716d92) if you have git checked out).

If you've already finished checking out the svn repository and want to make sure the master branch points to svn trunk, do the following.

**NOTE:** These instructions assume that you've committed or stashed any local changes you've made.  Use `git stash save` to save any uncommitted work and `git branch newbranchname` to create a branch to your last commit.

1. Switch to the master branch using `git checkout master` if you're not already there.  Use `git branch` to see your current branch, which is the one with an asterisk ('*') next to it.
2. Run `git svn info` and check the "`URL:`" field.  If the URL points to trunk, then you're done.  The next `git svn dcommit` will commit to trunk from the master branch.
3. If `git svn info` points to a tag or a branch URL, run `git log` and find the first commit that has a "`git-svn-id:`" URL that points to your svn trunk URL.  Copy the 40-character commit hash (on the line that starts with "commit") that represents this commit.
4. Reset your master branch to the commit hash using `git reset --hard commit-hash` replacing "`commit-hash`" with the commit hash from Step 3.

   **NOTE:** This step is the most dangerous one!  Be sure you've saved all of your work!  Make a tarball of your working directory if necessary.
5. Run `git svn info` again to make sure the "`URL:`" field shows you're on trunk.  If it does not, you copied the wrong commit hash in Step 3.  Go to Step 3 and try again.
6. Run `git svn rebase` to update your master branch to the latest revision on trunk in your svn repository.

**Pro Tip:** Experts will note that you can parse the "`git-svn-id:`" line at the bottom of each commit log to determine whether a particular commit is on trunk, on a tag or on a branch.  Thus it's sufficient to use `git log master` to check whether the first commit on the master branch is pointing to the trunk URL of your svn repository.